# Text Objects for displaying live text on screen with Processing + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I currently have a multi-class program that uses the processing library set up in Eclipse. I was wondering if there if there is a Text object in a 3rd party library somewhere that I can use to create text objects on the screen, and crucially, *move* these text objects around without having to redraw them to the screen. Are there any such classes out there?

Eg. a class called Text init as `Text textObject = new Text("String", x, y)`
with a method similar to `textObject.move(dx, dy)`

Comment: Are those the only requirements? Do you want the objects to draw themselves, or will you call their `draw()` manually?

Comment: I would preferably like them to draw themselves once the coordinates are passed in, but an explicit call would also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't find a library to do it, here's a minimal implementation. If you like, I could wrap it up in a library so that the objects draw themselves. If you're using eclipse, you'll probably need to add some `parent.`s before the PApplet calls.

```
TextObject to;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  to = new TextObject("test", 0, height/2);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  if(frameCount % 300 == 0) to.set(0, height/2);
  to.move(1,0);
  to.display();
}

class TextObject
{
  float x, y;
  String text;
  PFont f;

  TextObject(String s, float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.text = s;
    f = createFont("Georgia", 32);
  }
  TextObject(String s, float x, float y, PFont f){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.text = s;
    this.f = f;
  }
  void set(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  void move(float dx, float dy){
    x += dx;
    y += dy;    
  }
  void display(){
    textFont(f);
    text(text, x, y);
  }
}
```